# v-switch Returns False Value When It Checked

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem with v-switch. I have bunch of them on one page. When I check any one of them it returns false value.

```
<v-switch
    :name="['leave_it_' + listItem.asset_id]"
    @change="setAction(listItem)"
></v-switch>
```

Here is my script.

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      updates: {
        asset_id: [],
        leave_it: {},
        image: {},
        description: {}
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setAction(listItem) {
      var action = (document.querySelector('input[name="leave_it_' + listItem.asset_id + '"]:checked') ? "Leave it Alone" : "Take an Action");
      this.$set(this.updates.leave_it, listItem.asset_id, action);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

When I check the v-switch, DOM element becomes

```
<input aria-checked="true" role="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="leave_it_1" value="">
```

but the updates object becomes this:

```
updates:
  leave_it:
    1:"Take an Action"
```

As you can see even though aria-checked is true, object value is equal to false value.

So, please help me on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `v-switch`, using `v-model`, to a `data` value, and use that.

```
<v-switch
    v-model='switchValue'
    :name="['leave_it_' + listItem.asset_id]"
    @change="setAction(listItem)"
>
</v-switch>
```

```
data: {
  return {
     switchValue: false
  }
}
```

```
var action = this.switchValue ? "Leave it Alone" : "Take an Action";
```

Furthermore, you can lose the `:name` completely.  And instead of `@change` you can `watch` `switchValue`.  That's the *Vue way*.

```
watch:{
  theSwitch(newValue){
  }
}
```

Here is an example of binding multiple checkboxes.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js">
  js ">
</script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for='i of count'>
    <label>
       Item {{i}}
       <input v-model=checks[i] type='checkbox'></input>  
  </label>
  </div>

  <div>Values: {{checks}}</div>
</div>


<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      count: 10,
      checks: Array(10).fill(false),
    },
    watch: {
      checks(value) {
        console.log('value changed', value)
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Steven. I forgot to mention that I have bunch of switches. I think because of those multiple switches, what you suggest works when I check but it fails when I uncheck. I don't know why but it doesn't call the function when I add v-model.

Comment: Each switch needs a unique name, or you can bind them to an array.  What do you mean by 'it doesn't call the function'?  The watch function?

Comment: @BülentAkgül I added a snippet to show you how to bind multiple elements to an array and watch them.  You could also use a map with names as keys instead of an array.